# Cannot connect to Oracle: Oracle Error ORA-12650

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, jetty

I am trying to set up a connection to Oracle data source. Application is running under Jetty. Here's how i configured a data source in jetty-env.xml:

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="com.scc.gcm" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>com.scc.gcm</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
                <Set name="URL">user/pass@host/sid</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

Here's my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="Dora" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>com.scc.gcm</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="${hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I am able to connect to a schema with that credentials using sqlplus, but when creating EntityManagerFactory in application i am getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:297) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:221) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0"]
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
```

Comment: Don't know if it means anything, but don't give user/password in `URL` when giving them separately.

Comment: @Andreas Good point anyway, will check it out.